# Gold standard dataset for entity recognition in email

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for an annotated dataset for named entity recognition and classification which I could use as a gold standard. Preferably I'm looking for an email dataset, something like Enron (though I couldn't actually find a version with named entity labels anywhere). However other informal text would also do.

Comment: This qn belongs in the OpenData site :)